# proof the cellular boundary formula defines a chain complex

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

background:

> Denote by $X$ a finite CW-complex, $X_n$ its n-skeleton,
>   $e_i^k$ a k-cell and by $\varphi_i^k: D^k \to X$ its attaching map.
>   Note that $ {X_k}/{X_{k-1}} = \bigvee S_i^k $ a wedge sum of k-dimensional spheres where each sphere $ S_i^k $ corresponds to a cell $ e_i^k $.
>   If we define $ \alpha_{ij}^k : S^{k-1} \to S_j^{k-1} $ by the composition of the maps:
>   $$
> S^{k-1} \xrightarrow{\varphi_i^k |_{S^{k-1}}} {X_{k-1}}/{X_{k-2}} \xrightarrow{\text{projection}} {\left({X_{k-1}}/{X_{k-2}}\right)}/{\bigvee_{i \ne j} S_i^{k-1}} = S_j^{k-1}
> $$
>   and denote $ a_{ij}^k := deg(\alpha_{ij}^k) $, than we can define the cellular boundary maps $ \delta_k : E_k \to E_{k-1} $, where $ E_k := \text{span}_\mathbb{F}\{e_i^k\}_i $ by:
>   $$
> \delta_k e_i^k := \sum_j a_{ij}^k e_j^{k-1}
> $$
>   And we get that $ (E_k, \delta_k) $ is a chain complex and its homology groups are the cellular homology.

Normally (by what I saw on the web and in Hatcher), there is an abstract definition of the cellular homology via the singular homology groups $ H_n(X_n,X_{n-1}) $ and afterwards the boundary formula is deduced from it.
I'm trying (i.e. my professor told me) to go the other way around and define cellular homology more practically through the cellular boundary formula, without mentioning other homology theories, So the first thing is to show that the construction above is actually a chain complex.
I want to show that
$$
\delta_{k-1}(\delta_k(e_i^k)) = 0, \forall i
$$
Opening and rearranging we get:
$$
\delta_{k-1}(\delta_k(e_i^k) = \sum_t\left(\sum_j a_{ij}^k a_{jt}^{k-1}\right)e_t^{k-2}
$$
So we reduced the problem to showing that each coefficient is $0$:
$$
\sum_j a_{ij}^k a_{jt}^{k-1} = 0
$$
But i'm lost from here. I'd appreciate any help, clue or reference.